# ImageMagick convert crop with formatted filenames

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I am working with the ImageMagick convert program via command line. I am using it to split an image into **16x16 images**. This work well with the crop command. I do as such:

```
convert.exe "C:\Users\Matt\Desktop\tiles\maps\shrine_source\shadow_light.png" -crop 16x16 "C:\Users\Matt\Desktop\tiles\maps\shadow_light_input\shadow_light_%02d.png"
```

The problem is I would like to format the part after the underscore starting from an index. For instance, starting from "`shadow_light_2048.png`" and so forth. Looking at some examples I was thinking it could be done with bracket notations like "`shadow_light_%[2048-3071].png`", but it seems to ignore this.

Could someone help point me in the right direction on how to properly format to filename? Ideally in a way to where I only have to specify the starting index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `-scene` option to set the scene number which is what gets put where you use `%d`:

```
convert input.png -crop ... -scene 2048 result-%04d.png
```

So, for example, let's create a 20x20 black image and chop it up into tiles each 10x10:

```
convert xc:black[20x20] -crop 10x10 -scene 2048 tile-%d.png

-rw-r--r--   1 mark  staff       301 21 Jul 09:18 tile-2051.png
-rw-r--r--   1 mark  staff       301 21 Jul 09:18 tile-2050.png
-rw-r--r--   1 mark  staff       301 21 Jul 09:18 tile-2049.png
-rw-r--r--   1 mark  staff       280 21 Jul 09:18 tile-2048.png
```

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you for the solution and example.